# Gettin the info from Json file in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm new to the RoR. My question is: how can I get the Json info into my view files? Let me explain in details: I got data.json file and it contains like these info: 
[
     {
     "question" : "What's your name?",
     "answerA" : "Tom",
     "answerB" : "Bill",
     "answerC": "John",
     "answerD": "Foo"
     }
]

How can I use this data in my views? 
I'm trying to make a test(quiz) app, is there any gem for this? 
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the file in your controller:

```
def index
  file_path = "/your/file/path/data.json" # You can use Rails.root.join if it's in your Rails app
  @questions = JSON.parse(File.read(file_path.to_s))
end
```

You are good to go: use `@questions` in your Rails view, you are now able to access that json data.

Comment: Thanx, but it's giving the error: 'JSON::ParserError in TestsController#index
399: unexpected token at "]" ' What me to do?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanx a lot @Fire-Gragon-DoL

Comment: I fixed it (some error was in .json file). Thanx a lot. And here's the another problem: If I do like this:    <% @questions.each do |t| %>  <% t.question %>  <%= t.answerA  %>   It's giving me error. Or how can I use .json data as key => value. Help!?

Comment: `@questions.each { |question | puts question['question'].to_s + question['answerA'].to_s }` this is an example. For your syntax, there are various ways, you can check hashie: https://github.com/intridea/hashie or ruby openstruct: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html or you can write some plain old ruby objects and apply conversion manually.